# Is it right for me to say Java forces programmers to use OOP while C++ does not?

Tags: java, c++, oop

Java appears to force a programmer to use OOP the way I see it, while C++ does not so far as I am concerned....
I wish to know whether this is syntactically true for Java and C++

Comment: It's too opinion-based...

Comment: In C++ at least, if you won't write any OOP style in your code, you basically write C. C++ is not pure OOP but OOP is one of the major subjects in C++. I can't think of any good C++ code which won't include OOP style in it

Comment: flagged - opinion based

Comment: What is your reasoning behind this?

Comment: Well lets say with respect to their syntax it can be made more general because most built in function in java apart from the primitives types are OO

Comment: Java forces you to use objects in some instances (as a replacement for pointers, closures, ...) but you don't have to think and program object oriented.

Comment: ... though Java declares itself as an OO-language, while C++ claims to be multiparadigm. It's a matter of what the community thinks of the language.

Comment: "Real programmers can write FORTRAN in any language."

Comment: Pretty much true. C++ allows the programmer to choose what paradigm to use.

Comment: Most of the Java programs I've seen are full of non-OOP code, often in the form of classes with only (or mostly) static members, or classes littered with setters and getters. It almost makes you think that OOP is a mistake and programmers work hard to route around it.

Answer (score 1):

That is like saying Haskell forces programmer to use recursive calls. You can program procedurally in Java, and you can program with OOP mindset in C++. So neither answer is correct. But the concept is that in Java you should use OOP at all times and in C++ not, only if you wish so, but there is no one that can enforce it on you. (Maybe your boss by firing you, or SO being mean to you)

It is like firing a gun. You can either fire with the muzzle pointing at someone else (using OOP in Java) or look straight into the barrel while pulling the trigger (not using OOP in Java)